# SQL Server : How do I put a label on top of "Data Flow" tab of my ssis package?

Tags: ssis, label

SQL Server : How do I put a label on top of "Data Flow" tab of my ssis package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a label above the 'Data Flow' tab. The tabs are part of the SSIS interface. The only text above the tab is the name of the SSIS package (which of course you can rename as required).

You can add an annotation on the data flow design surface, by right-clicking and choosing 'Add Annotation..' from the menu.